# How to find the number of nodes at level k of a binary tree without using Breadth-first order traversal?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, binary-tree, tree-traversal

Given this binary tree (actually, the binary tree can be random and dynamic, this is just an example...):

See link for the binary tree image: [binary tree example](http://postimage.org/image/1j4pf6d1g/)

This are the given facts:

1. All nodes are connected to their father so that we can traverse from bottom to top (and of course top to bottom too).
2. All nodes hold information on how many descendants do they have in their left and right part.

The problem is this: I need to find a way to calculate the total number of nodes in level 2 (actually, in any level but for now, let's concentrate on level two). Obviously, the answer is 3 if we know the structure of the binary tree beforehand, but assume that we do not have this image, only the given facts.

Another catch here is we are going to start from a node that is in level 2 (our target level) and not the root. In this example, I've chosen NODE F.

I know that using the Breadth-first order traversal is the straight forward solution but I find it too time consuming since every time that I read a node, I will query it from a database.

I am looking for a more practical approach. But if it is "impossible" to solve this problem due to the insufficient given data, please let me know on what other data should be given in order for this to be solvable. I will assess it if it is feasible.

I am creating a website by the way and using PHP and MySQL. But I only want the concept or the explanation of the solution, more like an algorithm rather than a programming snippet or code...

I hope someone can answer me...Thank you very much!

Comment: is the tree stored in an array ?

Comment: No sir, I only have a table that stores every node information like who is the Left son, right son, father etc.. But preferably, I will use a link list for this since the binary tree can extend to any depth and is dynamic.

Comment: Can you put some test data somewhere on the net, so we could benchmark? Only the {id,pa,le,ri} nodes, no payload is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  "Breadth-first search" is the way to do it. But, if you don't want to use it i'd recommend to include pointers to brothers in the nodes. If you have to perform this kind of querys usually that would be a great saving.

**EDIT:**

If you can denormalize your nodes and store in the table the sibilings and level for all your nodes, then you can query without problems.

```
SELECT * FROM nodes where level=2
```

Comment: Yes sir, I was thinking of transferring the binary tree information from my database to a the memory using linked representation (pointer) binary tree data structure. But I have cannot come up with a solution for this one (except for the Breadth-first)...I really want to have a less time consuming solution (compared to the Breadth-first)

Comment: Can you use another datastore? Maybe mongodb. Has json-like documents that can represent trees really simple

Comment: BTW, are you really considering loading the hole tree in memory? I don't see that like an option

Comment: ah no sir, that's not what I meant,. I mean I am going to store node references, or in my case node ids, so that I can keep track of every unvisited node using a queue. And that is really not an option since my binary tree has the potential to extend more than 100th level!

Comment: Have you consider another datastructure? Like a B-TREE? That may help. Also, i figure out another thing, check the answer again.

Comment: No sir, any other kind of tree will not be accepted by the website since the nature of the operations are pure binary...

Comment: About your new answer sir,  but unfortunately, my binary tree does not have a stationary root. For example, Node F will be the root first, next will be Node C and lastly, node A. Since the root is moving, the levels are also moving and that makes the solution unreliable. I can't explain the whole function of my website here since it will take a lot of time for me to summarize it. But the problem that I imposed is the only thing that is missing from my solution and so I concentrated on this. Hmmm...It's very hard to explain in my part since my english is not that good..:D

Answer (score 1):

an option is too load the full table in php, and create a array tree. if you have a lot of rows (100k+), you can start the process before the table has finished loading, but you need more code to control it.

Alternativly, you can store the result at each node with a trigger.

**EDIT**: after thinking a bit, and reading the different answers and comments. I consider that the best option is to split the solution:

1. create a table nodesPerLevel, with 2 colums: level, nbNodes.
2. create a trigger on insert/delete of each node, that adds/substract 1 to the corresponding level in this new table.
3. when the result is needed, do `select sum(nbNodes) from nodesPerLevel where level >= ?`

Comment: I'll look up to it sir, hmm but I think that Breadth-first traversal will still be used in this approach...

Comment: the "final result stored in the node" is the fastest, but each insert and delete in the tree, cascade triggers updates for all siblings and parents. It's a though trade off. A compromise could be to store the final result once per level (in the left most element, or way better: in a separate dedicated table).

Comment: A very though trade off indeed, but still I am worried about the time that this approach will take since my website will perform this operation multiple times "per node" until the root is reached. So that means, this operation will be repeated 5 times if the starting point is on the 5th level, 100 times on the 100th level and so on...woah..

Comment: if it is for a large website, you can memcache the result each time you need. By experience, 20% of of the node will generate 80% of trafic (if not 5/95). Then @Tom answer is the way to go ;)

Comment: Your new solution is pretty much the same as @santiagobasulto, and I've explained why this approach can not be used in my binary tree..hmm...

Comment: that's because great minds meet ^^. If you want to improve performance, you have to change something. I'm afraid the answer isn't purely algorithmic here.

Answer (score 1):

For a tree in a DBMS you can use the WITH RECURSIVE cte-idiom and clip at the proper recursion level (== the recursion level of the given node, which will probably need another recursive subselect)

EDIT: (added code)

```
-- the test table
DROP table tree CASCADE;
CREATE table tree
    ( id CHAR(1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , pa CHAR(1) REFERENCES tree(id)
    , le CHAR(1)     REFERENCES tree(id)
    , ri CHAR(1) REFERENCES tree(id)
    );

-- generate some data
INSERT INTO tree (id, pa, le, ri) VALUES
      ( 'a', NULL, 'b', 'c' )
    , ( 'b', 'a', 'd', 'e' )
    , ( 'c', 'a', 'f', NULL )
    , ( 'd', 'b', 'g', NULL )
    , ( 'e', 'b', NULL, 'h' )
    , ( 'f', 'c', NULL, 'i' )
    , ( 'g', 'd', NULL, NULL )
    , ( 'h', 'e', NULL, NULL )
    , ( 'i', 'f', NULL, NULL )
    ;
-- a room with a view
CREATE VIEW reteview AS (
    WITH RECURSIVE re AS (
        SELECT 0 AS lev,id, pa, le, ri FROM tree
        WHERE pa IS NULL
        UNION
        SELECT 1+re.lev AS lev
        , tr.id,  tr.pa,  tr.le,  tr.ri
            FROM tree tr, re
            WHERE re.id = tr.pa
        )
    SELECT * FROM re
    );

/* EXPLAIN ANALYZE */ -- SELECT * FROM reteview ;

/* EXPLAIN ANALYZE */ SELECT re0.*
    FROM reteview re0
    , reteview re1
    WHERE re1.id = 'f'
    AND re0.lev <= re1.lev
    ;
```

Result:

```
 lev | id | pa | le | ri 
-----+----+----+----+----
   0 | a  |    | b  | c
   1 | b  | a  | d  | e
   1 | c  | a  | f  | 
   2 | d  | b  | g  | 
   2 | e  | b  |    | h
   2 | f  | c  |    | i
(6 rows)
```

Query plan (Postgres 9.01)

```
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=949.93..2773.55 rows=35167 width=36) (actual time=0.159..0.337 rows=6 loops=1)
   Join Filter: (re.lev <= re1.lev)
   ->  CTE Scan on re  (cost=474.97..566.71 rows=4587 width=36) (actual time=0.034..0.151 rows=9 loops=1)
         CTE re
           ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..474.97 rows=4587 width=36) (actual time=0.021..0.129 rows=9 loops=1)
                 ->  Seq Scan on tree  (cost=0.00..23.10 rows=7 width=32) (actual time=0.012..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
                       Filter: (pa IS NULL)
                 ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.28..36.01 rows=458 width=36) (actual time=0.018..0.022 rows=2 loops=4)
                       Hash Cond: (tr.pa = re.id)
                       ->  Seq Scan on tree tr  (cost=0.00..23.10 rows=1310 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.003 rows=9 loops=4)
                       ->  Hash  (cost=1.40..1.40 rows=70 width=12) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=2 loops=4)
                             Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                             ->  WorkTable Scan on re  (cost=0.00..1.40 rows=70 width=12) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=2 loops=4)
   ->  Materialize  (cost=474.97..578.52 rows=23 width=4) (actual time=0.013..0.018 rows=1 loops=9)
         ->  Subquery Scan on re1  (cost=474.97..578.40 rows=23 width=4) (actual time=0.111..0.157 rows=1 loops=1)
               ->  CTE Scan on re  (cost=474.97..578.17 rows=23 width=36) (actual time=0.110..0.156 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Filter: (id = 'f'::bpchar)
                     CTE re
                       ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..474.97 rows=4587 width=36) (actual time=0.008..0.135 rows=9 loops=1)
                             ->  Seq Scan on tree  (cost=0.00..23.10 rows=7 width=32) (actual time=0.002..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
                                   Filter: (pa IS NULL)
                             ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.28..36.01 rows=458 width=36) (actual time=0.021..0.024 rows=2 loops=4)
                                   Hash Cond: (tr.pa = re.id)
                                   ->  Seq Scan on tree tr  (cost=0.00..23.10 rows=1310 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.004 rows=9 loops=4)
                                   ->  Hash  (cost=1.40..1.40 rows=70 width=12) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=2 loops=4)
                                         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                                         ->  WorkTable Scan on re  (cost=0.00..1.40 rows=70 width=12) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=2 loops=4)
 Total runtime: 0.764 ms
(28 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing other than reading the tree from the root entirely up to level 2 and counting instances is to either set a relation field among instances of the same level or, if your data is too volatile for that approach to perform better, implement a short-timed but fast (memory?) [caching](http://memcached.org/) [system](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) that allows you to rapidly identify nodes of the same level.

Answer (score 0):

As your nodes are stored in database,  best solution could be SQL query like this (syntax may be wrong):

```
select count(third.id) from node as first, node as second, node as third where first.id =`your top node id`  and second.parent = first.id and third.parent =  second.id
```

Query like this will deliver  you nodes without extra trip to DB for every single node. But it may be costly for your database (dependeds on database and amount of nodes).  You could also  store level of node in node itself - this way query would be simpler and require less resources.

Comment: Hmmm..that would definitely shorten the time but I would like to have a solution that is independent to any programming language or technology, what I mean is that optimizing the time using only algorithms, or in this case, defeating the Breadth-first traversal approach...Hmm...

Comment: In my experience this method is way to costly for mysql. You better off to retrieve "flat" rows in php, and process the logic there. This is a different story if you use oracle 10+

Comment: Retrieval of flat rows in php will cost you time and memory on web tier - for certain amount of nodes  it could be impossible as well.  some graph oriented no sql database system may be better solution

Comment: These logical operations cost less in php than in mysql. Moreover, if these operation require access to other rows (like count subtree) (note: subtree != rows), then it's *ways* faster to do them in php hashtables (arrays) than in mysql. Mysql is good at retrivieving rows, executing orders... but not at "thinking". If size matters, you can process it in chunks. But you stand correct, mangodb, as memcached, or load balancing are options to improve performance, but not *mandatory* (yet ^^).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is

1.Find all paths of a tree

```
       50
     /    \
   30      60
 /   \    /  \
10   20  55   70
```

Paths are:

50-30-10
50-30-20
50-60-55
50-60-70

2.Store in Separate arrays .

3.Access the kth element in each array.

Some sudo code to find all paths :

```
Inorder(root)
{
 //do the required null checks
         if(root==null)
            return

  1.     PushOnStack(root->info)  

  2.     Inorder(root->left)

  3.     peekAllStackElement (read all the elements in stack and store in array an         reverse)

  4.     PopFromStack(root->info)         

  5.     Inorder(root->right)

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your data into a binary search tree, you can recurse it like below. Use recursion to keep track of the depth at each node in the tree.

On each recursive call, push the node at the current level to a hash table, using the level as your key and the node as your value.

In JavaScript, you can use an array or an object literal to do this. I'm storing everything in a JavaScript object literal which is similar to a hash table under the hood. Like this:

```
level = 0
object[level] = [node1] => { '0': [node, node2] }
object[level] = [node2] => { '0': [node1, node2] }

level = 1
object[level] = [node3] => { '0': [node, node2], '1': [node3] }
```

etc...

Before pushing, check to see if the key exists. If it doesn't exist, just insert the node into your hash wrapped in an array.

If a key exists (meaning there is a level collision), invoke collision resolution by simply pushing to the array at that key.

Now you have all the nodes at each level stored inside unique arrays inside an object. It should look like this:

```
{ '0': [ 20 ],
  '1': [ 8, 22 ],
  '2': [ 4, 12, 24 ],
  '3': [ 10, 14 ] } */
```

Or this if you're storing the entire node:

```
{ '0': [ { value: 20, right: [Object], left: [Object] } ],
  '1':
   [ { value: 8, right: [Object], left: [Object] },
     { value: 22, right: [Object], left: null } ],
  '2':
   [ { value: 4, right: null, left: null },
     { value: 12, right: [Object], left: [Object] },
     { value: 24, right: null, left: null } ],
  '3':
   [ { value: 10, right: null, left: null },
     { value: 14, right: null, left: null } ] }
```

You can do what you want with them after this. Sum the values at each level, convert to a linked list or, in your case, just check the length of the array at the desired level. This will give you the number of nodes.

```
BinaryTree.prototype.kNodesAtDepth = function(level) {

    var levels = {};

    var traverse = function(current, depth) {
        if (!current) return null;
        if (!levels[depth]) levels[depth] = [current.value];
        else levels[depth].push(current.value);
        traverse(current.left, depth + 1);
        traverse(current.right, depth + 1);
    };

    traverse(this.root, 0);
    return levels[level].length;
};

//tests
var bst = new BinaryTree();
bst.add(20, 22, 8, 4, 12, 10, 14, 24);
var nodeCount = bst.kNodesAtDepth(2); //3
console.log(nodeCount); //3
```